# Can I plug in 3 monitors into an nVidia GTX 550 Ti

Tags: multiple-monitors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to enable the use of triple monitors?](https://superuser.com/questions/299246/what-is-the-best-way-to-enable-the-use-of-triple-monitors)

[This card](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B004QTHZ5E/ref=oss_product) to be precise, the MSI MSIN550GTX-1GCY

It has 2 DVI outputs, and 1 HDMI, and my monitors have HDMI input.

Will I be able to plug in 3 monitors in there? (and have an extended desktop)

Or will the HDMI output only work as a "mirror", or something like that?

Also, is HDMI crisp clear? (As clear as DVI)
Or should I expect a blurry image?

Thank you!
Daniel

Comment: Please see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface#DVI_and_HDMI_compatibility) for differences between HDMI and DVI. For 90% of consumer use cases they will be identical.

Answer (score 3):

The 550Ti only has dual monitor support, You can either use the 2 DVI connectors or One DVI and One HDMI.

And for the HDMI quality:
It depents on your monitor and the resolution you want to use