# Suggest me GPU's & motherboard to set up 6 display's

Tags: windows-8, gpu, extended-desktop

I would like to setup 6 displays and need advice on which GPU or GPU's to buy and which motherboard can support them.

One display will be Dell U2412M and other 5 will be LG IPS225.

Dell U2412M should have the ability to switch between landscape and portrait without effecting the orientation of others.

Is any of the above possible? if so can you please suggest me the hardware.

Can i buy 1 660ti and connect it to Dell U2412m and buy 2 more cheap cards say gt630 and another gt640 to connect the other 5?

Thanks,
Srik

Comment: Yes, you can do that, or you could use an Eyefinity 7970 to do them all from 1 card. However, purchase recommendations are off-topic in SU.

Comment: Sorry didn't know about purchase recommendations. Eyeinfinity needs all monitors to be at same resolution, so i can't change orientation of one display without effecting others.

Comment: No, if you run an Eyefinity card but _don't enable Eyefinity_, they don't have to be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Eh, I'll make an answer post anyway, whatever)

It's probably easiest and cheapest to do this with a minimum of graphics cards, so you don't need a huge case and mobo. There are [Radeon HD 7970s that support 6 displays off one card](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814131474) [Note: you would need a ton of Mini-DP to DVI/HDMI adapters since your monitors don't have DP inputs], so you could do this in a decently small enclosure. Or you could put your 5 extra displays on an Eyefinity card and run your main from a separate one for higher performance. If you're going for the lowest possible price, there are multi-GPU solutions that will work as well, but compatibility may be an issue.

And yes, an Eyefinity card can be run in non-Eyefinity mode with 6 separate monitors.

> - Up to 6 displays supported
> - Independent resolutions, refresh rates, color controls, and video overlays

[[Source](http://www.powercolor.com/Global/products_features.asp?id=415)]

---

Edit: As for doing this without an Eyefinity card, [Nvidia does appear to support up to 6 total displays](https://superuser.com/a/299251/193093), and the [GT 640 appears to support 3 simultaneous outputs](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/geforce-gt-640-review,3214.html), so if I had to guess, I'd say the system you described ought to work. *(Note that most motherboards don't support enough PCIe bandwidth for 3 graphics cards to run really quickly, though this doesn't matter if you aren't running SLI; your other monitors will all be slow no matter what you do).*

Comment: Thanks Marcus, Mostly due to non availability of specialty products in mainstream market in my country, I am inclined to go with 3 gpu setup, 1 mid range gpu to power main display and 2 low end cards to power the other 5. Please confirm if this can be done?

Comment: I'm not positive there are nvidia cards that'll do 3 simultaneous display outputs, so you might want to do 3 cards with 2 monitors ea. (or get some midrange ATI stuff). Let me see if I can find a source for that, gimme a sec

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/299251/193093 There we go, at least nvidia definitely supports 6 monitors total. But I'm not sure of specifics of how exactly.

Comment: Edit: I lied! Yes, a 640 definitely suports 3 monitors simultaneously. [[Source](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/geforce-gt-640-review,3214.html)]

Comment: Excellent! only wish all 3 were digital lol

Comment: Ok, i found another brand with 3 digital outputs on a 640. One last question : When a card says 350w power required, does it mean it needs 350w for itself or the desktop need to have a total of 350 available?

Comment: If you see anything having to do with a number that high, I'm assuming it's referring to total desktop power. A GTX 660 Ti shouldn't be able to pull more than 150 watts tops.